# How can I use the same Word as in the function above? If ther's no way to do it how can I use the same random number without using a global variable?

Tags: python

```
def read_input(random_words):       
        word = choose_random_words()
        rand = random.randrange(0, 3)
    
        letter = find_row_letter(word[rand])
    
        print(rand)
    
        user_input = timed_input("Input: %s " % letter)

    
        return user_input
```

This function chooses a random word out of a list. This Word is then linked to a letter of the alphabet. You can see the timed_input as a normal input, as it is not important for my question.

```
def handle_input(random_words):     
    letter = read_input(random_words)
    
    word =
    
    print(letter)
    
    if word == letter:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("False")
```

In this function I want to compare if the user input from function read_input is the same as the chosen word from the same function.

Comment: I can't understand how a word could be equal to one of its letter

Answer (score 1):

Make `read_input` return the `word` too

```
def read_input(random_words):
    word = choose_random_words()
    rand = random.randrange(0, 3)
    letter = find_row_letter(word[rand])
    user_input = timed_input("Input: %s " % letter)
    return user_input, word


def handle_input(random_words):
    letter, word = read_input(random_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is declare the word variable to be global:

```py
def read_input(random_words):  
        global word
        word = choose_random_words()
        rand = random.randrange(0, 3)
    
        letter = find_row_letter(word[rand])
    
        print(rand)
    
        user_input = timed_input("Input: %s " % letter)
    
        return user_input
```

That allows you to access the `word` variable from anywhere.